# html&js vadilation of radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hey everone, I am trying to make a validation of radio button. Once submit without clicking the button, it will be a red warning text next to the text-input as this image** [image: vadilation of radio button]

The code is below here,I am very appreciated if someone fixes this problem.

````
<html>
<head>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="456.css">

  <meta charest ="utf-8">
  <title>error-msg will not display correctly at the same time</title>

  <script>
function validation(thisForm) {

 
    // other
    if(!thisForm.other.value.length)
    {
      document.getElementById('other-error').style.display= "inline-block";

    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('other-error').style.display= "none";

    }
    
            
    
  if (!thisForm.other.value.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
  </script>
  <style> 
  .error-msg {
  display: none;
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;

}
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" onSubmit="return validation(this);">

  <fieldset>

    <div class="Other">
      <label for="other">Other</label>
      <input type="radio" id="other" name="other" /> 
      <input type="text" id="o-text" name="o-text">
      <span class="error-msg" id="other-error">other error</span>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: what is the issue here ?

Comment: need a red display:inline-block next to the input of other, if the radio button is not clicked.

Comment: i am not sure but you have a typo in js you getById `other-other` and element id is `other`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just check with checked property.

```
if(document.getElementById("yourRadiobuttonID").checked==false){
 document.getElementById('other-error').style.display= "inline-block";
}
else{
document.getElementById('other-error').style.display= "none";
}
```